# PowerShell stdout trouble

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, stdout

A legacy program "LegacyBuilder" runs "batch.cmd" file and then redirects its output to a file, like this.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\batch.cmd");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
{
    using (StreamWriter logWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt"))
    {              
        while ((logLine = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            logWriter.WriteLine(logLine);
        }
    }
}
```

The batch.cmd contains this line

```
C:\SomeApp.exe "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

SomeApp.exe is using the following method from a different assembly.

```
SomeAssembly.SomeClass.GenerateOutput()
```

This GenerateOutput method create a process to a 3rd party console program. After troubles with buffer deadlocking, I discovered (from another SO question I think) the following code never cause such deadlock and output of the 3rd party program is captured by the "LegacyBuilder".

```
Console.Write("I'm creating the process!");

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\3rdPartyConsoleExe.exe");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {    
       process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
       {
         if (e.Data == null) outputWaitHandle.Set();
         else output.AppendLine(e.Data);
       };
       process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
       {
         if (e.Data == null) errorWaitHandle.Set();
         else error.AppendLine(e.Data);
       };

    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    if (process.WaitForExit(60000) && outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(60000) && errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(60000))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());

        if (process.ExitCode > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("PROCESS COMPLETED ExitCode=" + process.ExitCode.ToString());
    }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("PROCESS TIMED OUT");
    }
}
```

Please note the Console.Write("I'm creating the process!");

So far so good, everything is working, all output is being captured by the "LegacyBuilder"

Now, batch.cmd was updated with calling a powershell script.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -File "C:\powershellscript.ps1"
```

The powershell script basically loads the SomeAssembly, creates SomeObject and then calls the GenerateOutput method. Like this.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\SomeAssembly.dll";
$someCls = New-Object SomeAssembly.SomeClass()
$someCls.GenerateOutput();
```

The problem: The text "I'm creating the process!" is being captured by the "LegacyBuilder" so this is going to stdout.

But the expected output of the GenerateOutput() method is not generating anything and after several attempted calls it gets deadlocked again. Not even "PROCESS TIMED OUT" gets called.

This is weird.

batch.cmd calls "SomeApp.exe" which calls SomeAssembly.SomeClass.GenerateOutput(). The output of the 3rd party program is present in the file and the batch.cmd successfully continues.

batch.cmd calls powershell which loads a script which create SomeAssembly.SomeClass object and then call GenerateOutput() method. The output is not present, only output from direct Console.Write calls is ... after several attemps, it gets deadlocked and batch.cmd never continues.

Any help? I wish something like "StopBufferDeadlocksInPowershell -includeStupidLegacyNestedProcessCalls" existed...

**EDIT 1**

I would love to avoid making any changes in "LegacyBuilder" since the code in it is really, really complex (the topmost code sample is just simplification) and while I'd love to rewrite it completely, it would be very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of headaches, somehow, this made it working.

```
$someCls.GenerateOutput() | Out-Host;
```

The buffer is no longer deadlocked.